# How to apply the wilcox.test to a whole dataframe in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame with one grouping factor (the first column) with multiple levels (more than two) and several columns with data. I want to apply the *wilcox.test* to the whole date frame to compare the each group variables with the others. How can I do this?

UPDATE:
I know that the *wilcox.test* will only test for difference between two groups and my data frame contains three. But I am interested more in how to do this, than what test to use. Most likely that one group will be removed, but I have not decided yet on that, so I want to test all variants.

Here is a sample:

```
structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), var1 = c(9.3, 
9.05, 7.78, 7.11, 7.14, 8.12, 7.5, 7.84, 7.8, 7.52, 8.84, 6.98, 
6.1, 6.89, 6.5, 7.5, 7.8, 5.5, 6.61, 7.65, 7.68), var2 = c(11L, 
11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L), var3 = c(7L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 
5L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 2L), 
    var4 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 
    11L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 11L), var5 = c(11L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 
    8L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 9L)), .Names = c("group", "var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone for all answers!

Comment: `wilcox.test` will only test for difference between two groups. Your data frame contains three. Are you sure this is the test you want and if so, is it all possible pairwise tests you want?

Comment: @RoyalTS, I know about that. But I am interested more in how to do this,  than what test to use. Suppose that one group will be removed, but I have not decided yet on that, therefore I want to test all variants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updating my answer to work across columns

```
test.fun <- function(dat, col) { 

 c1 <- combn(unique(dat$group),2)
 sigs <- list()
 for(i in 1:ncol(c1)) {
    sigs[[i]] <- wilcox.test(
                   dat[dat$group == c1[1,i],col],
                   dat[dat$group == c1[2,i],col]
                 )
    }
    names(sigs) <- paste("Group",c1[1,],"by Group",c1[2,])

 tests <- data.frame(Test=names(sigs),
                    W=unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$statistic)),
                    p=unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$p.value)),row.names=NULL)

 return(tests)
}


tests <- lapply(colnames(dat)[-1],function(x) test.fun(dat,x))
names(tests) <- colnames(dat)[-1]
# tests <- do.call(rbind, tests) reprints as data.frame

# This solution is not "slow" and outperforms the other answers significantly: 
system.time(
  rep(
   tests <- lapply(colnames(dat)[-1],function(x) test.fun(dat,x)),10000
  )
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.056   0.000   0.053
```

And the result:

```
tests

$var1
                Test  W          p
1 Group 1 by Group 2 28 0.36596737
2 Group 1 by Group 3 39 0.05927406
3 Group 2 by Group 3 38 0.27073136

$var2
                Test    W         p
1 Group 1 by Group 2 19.0 0.8205958
2 Group 1 by Group 3 36.5 0.1159945
3 Group 2 by Group 3 40.5 0.1522726

$var3
                Test    W         p
1 Group 1 by Group 2 13.0 0.2425786
2 Group 1 by Group 3 23.5 1.0000000
3 Group 2 by Group 3 41.0 0.1261647

$var4
                Test  W         p
1 Group 1 by Group 2 26 0.4323470
2 Group 1 by Group 3 30 0.3729664
3 Group 2 by Group 3 29 0.9479518

$var5
                Test    W         p
1 Group 1 by Group 2 24.0 0.7100968
2 Group 1 by Group 3 19.0 0.5324295
3 Group 2 by Group 3 17.5 0.2306609
```

Comment: Thank you, Brandon! To analyse all variables, I added a second loop to your code (see the last update in my question), but I do not know how to adapt it further. Now is printed only the results for the last variable, not all. Can you help?

Comment: The information you want is already contained in `sigs`, all you have do is access it. I've updated my answer in response.

Comment: I like your answer, but I mean you analyse only one variable, while the dataset contains 5 variables.

Comment: When I first read your question, I thought you only wanted to test against one column. I think the other two solutions are more complete, and you can explore the results in much the same way as I've described above. Although I don't want to comment on the use of alternative tests.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brandon!
Also thanks to everyone for all answers, I learned something from each of you!

Comment: Brandon, your code don't have the `sigs <- list()` line, so it not works and it produce this error: `Error in sigs[[i]] <- wilcox.test(dat[dat$group == c1[1, i], col], dat[dat$group ==  : object 'sigs' not found`. If I add the line `sigs <- list()`, it works, but in results disappear the names of variables. If I remove again the line `sigs <- list()` (in the same work session), the names of variables appears. Why this happens? I am working in JGR+Deducer.

Comment: Whoopsie. I'll fix that. I left it out, but you probably just put the initialization within the for loop rather than outside it.

Comment: Now is OK, thanks! But I encountered another problem. The resulted output of analysing my real data is a list with 116 elements (big tables). Can this list somehow be formatted or exported, so I can copy/paste it to an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @lurie I think it's best if you ask a new question with your new problem.

Answer (score 14):

The `pairwise.wilcox.test` function seems like it would be useful here; perhaps like this?

```
out <- lapply(2:6, function(x) pairwise.wilcox.test(d[[x]], d$group))
names(out) <- names(d)[2:6]
out
```

If you just want the p-values, you can go through and extract those and make a matrix.

```
sapply(out, function(x) {
    p <- x$p.value
    n <- outer(rownames(p), colnames(p), paste, sep='v')
    p <- as.vector(p)
    names(p) <- n
    p
})
##         var1      var2      var3 var4      var5
## 2v1 0.5414627 0.8205958 0.4851572    1 1.0000000
## 3v1 0.1778222 0.3479835 1.0000000    1 1.0000000
## 2v2        NA        NA        NA   NA        NA
## 3v2 0.5414627 0.3479835 0.3784941    1 0.6919826
```

Also note that `pairwise.wilcox.test` adjusts for multiple comparisons using the Holm method; if you'd rather do something different, look at the `p.adjust` parameter.

Comment: Heureka, there's a `pairwise.wilcox.test`! That's much better than throwing `wilcox.test' at each pair of groups individually.

Comment: Something is wrong with the matrix - see row 3 and column for *var4*?

Comment: I think it's correct; row 3 is testing against itself, which doesn't make sense, so is NA; and for var4, the uncorrected p-values are large enough that the Holm correction makes them all equal to one.

Comment: Thank you very much, also thanks to @royalts for your answers, I learned something from each of you!

Answer (score 6):

You can loop over the columns using `apply` and then pass the columns to whatever test you want to use using an anonymous function, like so (assuming the data frame is named `df`):

```
apply(df[-1],2,function(x) kruskal.test(x,df$group))
```

Note: I used the Kruskal-Wallis test because that works on multiple groups. The above would work just as well using the Wilcoxon test if there were only two groups.

If you *do* want to do pairwise Wilcoxon tests on all variables, here's a two-liner that will loop through all columns and all pairs and return the results as a list:

```
group.pairs <- combn(unique(df$group),2,simplify=FALSE)
# this loops over the 2nd margin - the columns - of df and makes each column
# available as x
apply(df[-1], 2, function(x)
             # this loops over the list of group pairs and makes each such pair
             # available as an integer vector y
             lapply(group.pairs, function(y)
                    wilcox.test(x[df$group %in% y],df$group[df$group %in% y])))
```

Comment: You can write `apply(df[-1],2,kruskal.test,df$group)` instead.