# How to apply wilcox.test to compare every column of table

Tags: r

I have a data table in r called tbl.
I want to perform a wilcox test to compare every column with every other column in the table and store the p-values in a new table or matrix.

To compare a single pair of columns (1 and 2 in this case) I would normally just do this:

```
wilcox.test(tbl[,1],tbl[,2],alternative="t",paired=FALSE)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this older post can help you out. [link to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271449/how-to-apply-the-wilcox-test-to-a-whole-dataframe-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to store the 2-way combinations of your `tbl` and then use `lapply` to calculate the p.values. Something like this:

```
#example data.frame
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b= runif(10), c=runif(10))

#calculate combinations of names
combinations <- as.data.frame(combn(names(df), 2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#use the above combinations and calculate the wilcox.test to get the p.values
lapply(combinations, function(x) {
  wilcox.test(df[,x[1]] , df[, x[2]], alternative="t", paired=FALSE)$p.value
})
```

Output:

```
$V1
[1] 0.8534283

$V2
[1] 0.2175626

$V3
[1] 0.3526814
```

Comment: If you do not specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the combinations data.frame, the names will be saved as factors and only `1` and `2` will be fed to the `lapply` function later resulting in getting the same p.value every time. This is very important.