# Splitting data set and creating two groups

Tags: r, split, grouping

This should be a very simple code question to many of you, but I am brand new to R and struggling with the basics.

I have a simple csv data of 500 observations, with a header, and I am trying to split it into two groups (cut at row 251) and name them A and B so that I keep running tests on them separately.

I have tried the split function, but I cannot get the code right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `dataseta <- dataset[as.numeric(rownames(df))<=251,]; datasetb <- dataset[as.numeric(rownames(df))>251,]`?

Comment: `split(df, rep(c("A", "B"), each=250))` will give you a list of two dataframes.

Comment: Is there a feature in the data set that makes you want to split them at row 251? Or is it just a matter of dividing the data set in half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
A=df[1:251,]
B=df[252:nrow(df),]
```

is this pretty enough?

Comment: This function works as well, I think it does the same as suggested by Ronak. However I still cannot see the data or run the t test as I would like, in the way I answered to his post above. Any suggestions?

Comment: @holandgents506 This sounds like a formatting problem. Can you post a sample of your data by using `dput()`, otherwise tell us at least what class your data is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` which will return you list of two dataframes.

```
list_df <- split(df, rep(c(1, 2), each = nrow(df)/2))
```

But if you want only two groups, you could do

```
A = df[1:250, ]
B = df[251:500, ]
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps. However, when I type just "A", to see the values, I get them all as "NA", for either A or B. Any idea why this might be?
Also, if I try to run a t.test, just typing "t.test(a,b)", I also get an error message. Something like "the predicted value "x" has not enough entries.

Comment: @holandgents506 have you read the data into R ? What is it called? I have used `df` here. Can you check `nrow(df)` ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, That took care of it. For the t.test(a,b) it works fine, but if I try to run a Wilcoxon test, wilcox.test(a,b)$p.val I get an error message. Any idea why? Thanks again

Comment: @holandgents506 How do you want to apply the wilcox.test ?  You could do `wilcox.test(unlist(A),  unlist(B))` or apply `pairwise.wilcox.test` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271449/how-to-apply-the-wilcox-test-to-a-whole-dataframe-in-r