# One-Sample Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test over multiple columns in R

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to use a one-sample Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test to test whether each column in R is significantly greater than 0. I can go through each column individually, but I would ideally like to use `lapply` to cycle through each column and record the p-values in a separate dataframe. Each row of the dataframe lists monthly values for a given year:

```
df = data.frame("year"=c(1:20), "jan"=runif(20), "feb"=runif(20))
```

... with 13 total columns for year and each month.

The code I am using now compares each column to zero, but I would like to incorporate the `lapply` function to streamline things a bit:

```
wilcox.test(df[,1], mu=0, alternative="greater")
```

I have tried:

```
res = lapply(df, function(x){
      wilcox.test(df[,x[1]], mu=0, alternative="greater")
      })
```

But I am getting an error that my input to the `wilcox.test` function is not numeric which makes me think it is not reading in individual columns.I have tried using some suggestions in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271449/how-to-apply-the-wilcox-test-to-a-whole-dataframe-in-r) but am having trouble modifying the code to work for a one-sample test.  I am new to `lapply` and writing functions, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly apply over columns in a `data.frame` with `lapply`. Make sure that you only pass columns that contain numeric values by subsetting to only those columns.

```
lapply(df[,2:13],function(x){wilcox.test(x, mu=0, alternative="greater")})
```

Your version doesn't work because you are trying to subset `df` by an entire column of `df` (ie `df[,df[,1]]`, instead of `df[,1]`).

To streamline things even further, you can use `sapply`, and `$p.value` to access just the p-value results.

```
sapply(df[,2:13],function(x){wilcox.test(x, mu=0, alternative="greater")$p.value})
#         jan          feb          mar          apr          may          jun          #jul          aug          sep          oct          nov 
#9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 9.536743e-07 
#         dec 
#9.536743e-07
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(year = 1:20, lapply(rep(20,12),runif))
names(df)[2:13] <- tolower(month.abb)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! I also added ```df_pvalue = data.frame("month"=c(1:12),
                              "p-value"=sapply(df[,2:13],function(x){wilcox.test(x, mu=0, alternative="greater")$p.value}))``` to make a dataframe with the months and p-values